# How to make my Samsung Galaxy S7 with android 7 always discoverable on bluetooth scans?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-7.0-nougat, samsung-galaxy

i want to make my new samsung galaxy S7 (SM-G930F) always discoverable on bluetooth scans in my android app.
I tried this code:

```
discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 0);
            startActivityForResult(discoverableIntent, REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE_CODE);
```

This works fine with all devices that i used:

-Samsung Galaxy S4 mini (GT-I19195) with CyanogenMod Android 6;

-Asus Zenfone3 (Z012S) with android 7;

-Samsung Galaxy S3  (GT-I19300) with CyanogenMod Android 6.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having experienced this same issue with the Samsung S6, i believe it's not possible to permanently set it as discoverable with Samsung devices.